# pandas: accessing Period-indexed data with Timestamps

Tags: python, pandas

With Pandas 0.15.2, I'm creating a timeseries with Periods (Timespans) as indices:

```
periods = pandas.PeriodIndex([pandas.Period('2015-01-01'), pandas.Period('2015-01-02')])
series = pandas.TimeSeries([1,2], index=periods)
```

This makes my series variable look like

```
In [21]: series
Out[21]: 
2015-01-01    1
2015-01-02    2
Freq: D, dtype: int64
```

Now that my data is indexed by periods, I can get the data for a timestamp inside one of these periods simply with

```
In [22]: series[pandas.Timestamp('2015-01-01-15h')]
Out[22]: 1
```

However, I can't use a date range as index:

```
In [23]: dates = pandas.date_range('2015-01-01-15h', periods=5, freq='3H')

In [24]: series[dates]
Out[24]: 
2015-01-01 15:00:00   NaN
2015-01-01 18:00:00   NaN
2015-01-01 21:00:00   NaN
2015-01-02 00:00:00   NaN
2015-01-02 03:00:00   NaN
Freq: 3H, dtype: float64
```

I was hoping for an output like

```
2015-01-01 15:00:00   1
2015-01-01 18:00:00   1
2015-01-01 21:00:00   1
2015-01-02 00:00:00   2
2015-01-02 03:00:00   2
Freq: 3H, dtype: float64
```

Why can Pandas look up the value of a single timestamp in my Periods-based series,
but not the values of an array of timestamps? Is there another way to achieve this?
I can use the following:

```
for d in dates:
    print(series[d])
```

but it would be nice to spare those extra lines.

**Edit:** I created a small subclass of Timeseries:

```
class MySeries(pandas.TimeSeries):

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if type(key) != pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex:
            return super(MySeries, self).__getitem__(key)
        else:
            values = [self[k] for k in key]
            return pandas.TimeSeries(values, key)
```

that allows me to use `series[dates]` with the behaviour I wanted. I'd still be interested in knowing why the default behaviour when using a date range is different than when using a single date.

Answer (score 2):

You could to this:

```
series[dates.to_period(periods.freq)]
```

to get this:

```
2015-01-01    1
2015-01-01    1
2015-01-01    1
2015-01-02    2
2015-01-02    2
Freq: D, dtype: int64
```

Where `dates.to_period(periods.freq)` converts your `dates` into comparable with your `index` time series:

```
dates.to_period(periods.freq)
<class 'pandas.tseries.period.PeriodIndex'>
[2015-01-01, ..., 2015-01-02]
Length: 5, Freq: D
```

Comment: +1 for a working solution to my problem, although this doesn't answer the question why the behaviour is different when using a range of dates than when using just one date as index

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're running into is because with your lines:

```
dates = pandas.date_range('2015-01-01-15h', periods=5, freq='3H')
series[dates]
```

you are attempting to index the `series` data with a `DatetimeIndex`, but you have set the index of `series` with a `PeriodIndex` with these lines:

```
periods = pandas.PeriodIndex([pandas.Period('2015-01-01'), pandas.Period('2015-01-02')])
series = pandas.TimeSeries([1,2], index=periods)

Out[12]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2015-01-01, ..., 2015-01-09]
<class 'pandas.tseries.period.PeriodIndex'>
[2015-01-01, 2015-01-09]
```

So @Primer's answer solves this issue by making your indices type consistent (e.g. `PeriodIndex` for both).